# Remove the kicking command, or improve it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, moderation

Kicking in chat is pretty useless and/or pointless. Everything that happens when you are kicked is, you are sent to the room list. There's no kick message, no "kicked by" message, no kick reason, nothing. For all a user knows, it's either a transient bug or a network hiccup. How is that useful?

The user can also immediately rejoin the chat. There's no repercussions for the user being kicked, it's just annoying. Even as a mod-only tool it's basically useless and annoying/confusing rather than a helpful moderation tool.

You may want to consider either removing it, or turning it into something more effective -- maybe user-specific room-specific 30 seconds long silencing.

Comment: Or stop useless flagging, so I don't have to annoy you ;-)

Comment: Mods can also suspend for an hour.  A much more useful tactic.

Comment: @Ivo How is associating a [room about LaTeX](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/176/in-which-the-relative-merits-of-word-and-latex-are-discussed) to the LaTeX site useless? Maybe you are not aware this is a moderator only option.

Comment: Owners of a room can change the association, can't they?

Comment: @Rebecca No they can't. I would've just done that myself, if I could've.

Comment: It changed?  I'm pretty sure they could before. Hrm.

Comment: @Rebecca No, it was always that way -- but you, as a mod, could never notice :) What did change is that new rooms are automatically associated with your user's main chat accounts' site (originally, there was no default association.)

Comment: I know I'm not a good test case, but I thought I had walked another user through doing it.  I'm well aware of the default association.

Comment: @Rebecca Isn't the association setting supposed to be under [room info → edit](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/chat_migration_not_there.png), together with the room name and description options? I think I recall screenshots about it :)

Comment: @Cross Your appreciation for nukes is duly noted, but that's quite the heavy handed measure.

Comment: Yes, the host option.  Guess it did change or I'm hallucinating.

Comment: Kicking is just supposed to be a warning.  If further actions need to be taken, then so be it, but kicking is supposed to be a step-one wake-up call to the user.

Comment: @Rebecca My point exactly is that the wake up call is broken as it is.

Comment: Back up that statement?  I don't see it.

Comment: @Rebecca _Everything_ that happens when you are kicked is, you are sent to the room list. There's no kick message, no "kicked by" message, no kick reason, nothing. For all a user knows, it's either a transient bug or a network hiccup. How is that useful?

Comment: So is the feature request to remove the command or make it obvious what has happened?  *confused*

Comment: @Rebecca I'm giving attention to a problem and suggesting a few ways to improve the situation. I don't have a magic wand that gives the perfect solution to problems, so I prefer to maybe use the answers part to discuss possible fixing solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to agree with you.

Although I somewhat like the room-and-user-specific short-term silencing idea, here are the issues I see:

- Is there a problem this solves? Has there ever been a situation were silencing a user in just *one* room and for a short time would actually help with anything?
- In particular, if a user behaves in such a way that they have to be silenced, does it really make sense to do this in just one room?

I'm interested to hear about ideas, but currently I err on the side of just removing this "option".

Comment: I just thought moderators could already suspend users for arbitrary times such as 30 seconds :)

Comment: @radp: no, suspension is 1 hour minimum (well, unless you manually unsuspend before)

Answer (score 1):

Well looks like room owners can no longer kick.

So now you know that it had to be a mod.

While I'm sad to see it go, I see the potential missuse, as before it was *too* easy to kick some one from a room.

Comment: It was fun once, we had a owner and kicking war in a test room once here, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5134404#5134404

Comment: either that or the mods were having fun, and everyone was just jumping back into the room...

Comment: Ah, here is something, shows that owners could kick at one time, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/87773/7